# Unmatched [ in regex, despite being escaped

Tags: regex, perl

Trying to test out the position function and parsing abilities of perl. I have a regex, which I think is correct, but perl is telling me I have an unmatched [, but to me it looks escaped.

> Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\G.*[([ <-- HERE ^]+)]/ at perltest.pl line 5.

Can anyone clarify why I'm getting that message from the following code?

```
my $string = "one, [two] , [three], and [four].";

pos($string) = 0;
while (my $string =~ m{\G.*\[([^\]+)\]}cg)
{
    my $value = $1;
    print "Found value $value .\n";
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The negated character class is not terminated.

Where you have

```
[^\]+    # One or more characters that aren't «]», «+», ...
```

you should have

```
[^\]]+   # One or more characters that aren't «]»
```

I would even use

```
[^[\]]*  # Zero or more characters that aren't «[» or «]»
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is from having a incomplete character class ...

```
\G.*\[([^\] +)\]
           ^
```

To solve this problem, you need to add a closing bracket to complete the class.

```
\G.*\[([^\]]+)\]
           ^
```

I propose the following, while changing `+` to `*` to match "zero or more" instead.

```
[^]]*
```

Answer (score 2):

You've only escaped 3 out of 4.

```
m{\G.*\[([^\]+)\]}cg)
       ^    ^   ^
         ^ - not escaped
```

Comment: Only three of the four should be escaped. The problem is that a `]` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Explaining the regex of the question:

```
m{\G.*\[([^\]+)\]}cg
```

This regex is a escaped perl regex.
The unescaped regex is: `\G.*\[([^\]+)\]`

The regex: `\G.*\[([^\]+)\]` does:

- `\G` ... Assert that the position is at the end of the previous match, or the start of the string.
- `.*` ... Match any character that is not a line break character, between zero and unlimited times. (greedy)
- `\[` ... Match the character [

Now the regex cant be processed, there is an opening paranthesis without a closing paranthesis.
This is because after the opening paranthesis `(` there starts a character class `[` that would need to be closed before the close paranthesis `)` .
Allthough there is a `\]` this is a escaped `]` and thus not the closing bracket of the character class.
So the `)` in the regex is part of the opened character class.
Since the last `]` is also escaped neither the Capturing group nor the character class is closed.

In Perl Regular expression the `]` does not need to be escaped.
The end of a character class must not be escaped.

If `\[([^\]+)\]` is meant to match all characters between `[` and `]` and capture its value into capturing group 1 the corrected part is: `\[([^\]]+)\]` or even shorter `\[([^]]+)]`

So the closest working regex is:

```
\G.*\[([^\]]+)\]
```

and can be shortened to

```
\G.*\[([^]]+)]
```

---

If you want to match `two` `three` and `four`:

```
m/\[([^]]+)]/
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why OP's getting the error in the first place? That seems to be the main question, and not just the correct regex

Answer (score 0):

You might find that adding whitespace to the regex to make it more readable can help you see what's going on.  Plus you have too many "my $string"s in there :-)

```
my $string = "one, [two] , [three], and [four].";

while ($string =~ m{
        \G.*
        \[
            (  [^\]]+  )
        \]
    }cgx)
{
    my $value = $1;
    print "Found value $value .\n";
};
```